# Very slow DNS lookup regardless of DNS server I use

Tags: networking, dns, performance, internet, internet-connection

**No duplication. I checked all** other questions with similar title and none the answers works. Also it often is different issue.

**Issue:**

Whenever I'm making connection to website/server that I didn't visit just recently the load times are horrendous. Sometimes it takes 10-15 seconds to even start loading the page.

**Eliminated issues**

- I'm using DELL workstation with i7 7th gen processor and 64GB of RAM
  and NVME SSD running Windows 10.
- ISP. The same issue happened when using LTE modem
- All browsers and all software that uses internet shows the same issues.
- I don't run any antivirus except Windows Defender.
- No VPN
- No Proxy

**DNS Servers**

I tried using nearly all alternative DNS servers. All with the same issue. I even run DNS Benchmark and chose OpenDNS as it is the fastest. But again. I checked good 10 alternatives.

**I noticed**

That when running DNS query sniffer all entries are duplicated. And only once for each domain goes to the Open DNS (or any DNS I set in settings). I don't know if that is the issue.

**Screenshot time**
[image: Duplicated DNS lookups]
[image: Google Chrome diagnostic]
[image]

[image: Network Adapters]
[image: Tracert to www.google.com]

**UPDATE**
I included screenshot of all my network adapters. I'm only using the Ethernet one right now. Before you comment that it is too many... Some time ago (about 2 weeks) it was all working perfectly fine with the same amount of adapters.

I also added tracert to www.google.com

Comment: How many network adapters do you have (including VPN if any)? A `tracert` run might be useful.

Comment: @harrymc I added information you asked for. In short. Networks adapters didn't change. It was working fine about a week or 2 ago with the same network adapters. I also added tracert.

Comment: Try to temporarily disable all adapters except for Ethernet.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for help. It was DNS in the "Hyper-V Internal" network adapter. Traffic goes through it (I have no idea why), and it had internal work VPN setup. But as I"m forced to work from home, it was unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I found what was wrong. It is all because of COVID-19 (Partially, but still).

As @harrymc suggested I disabled all virtual network adapters (I work on many virtual machines). It the "main" virtual adapter I had my internal work DNS setup. It was unreachable from home (this is part where COVID-19 takes place, I was forced to work from home).

I simply removed that DNS from this network adapter and all is well now.

So. If you have rat nest of virtual adapters, check if DNS for "main" one is configured correctly.